# Intent.ACTION_CALL problem(SecurityException)

Tags: android

I have use this intent to dial a no which is written in the setdatafield of the Intent
But when I run app and click on the button of call where i put this intent i got this error in LogCat

```
06-14 14:08:10.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2898): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:2125551212  cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{43edbe18 2898:com.collabera.labs.sai/10102} (pid=2898, uid=10102) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

The Intent.ACTION_DIAL intent (instead of Intent.ACTION_CALL) doesn't need a permission. It only brings up the dialer so the user can decide himself whether or not to call, which is a better user experience in most cases anyway.

Comment: such a small detail but so important +1

Answer (score 10):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:03000000000"));           
        startActivity(intent);
```

**Add Permission**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a clue in the error: `requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE`

You need to declare the `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission in your manifest:

```
<manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="yourpackage"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
        .
        .
        .
</manifest>
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"></uses-permission>
```

it's deprecated constant but it helps to start a call instantly without dialer activity opening

Comment: i think you are talking about <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

Answer (score 1):

Add permission in your `manifest.xml` like so

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Read more on `Permissions` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)