# Android Intent Calling

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to make a call when I click on Android Mobile field with this code

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);           
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+contactNo));   
startActivity(callIntent);
```

And added these in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And finally I am getting `**java.lang.SecurityException**` exception.

Why it Happens? and What is the Correct Procedure to Make a Call when click on Contact field?

Comment: show your manifest please .

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent.ACTION\_CALL problem(SecurityException)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341076/intent-action-call-problemsecurityexception)

Comment: Means? I am using only one time

Comment: permission should be under manifest

Comment: @maheshd show your manifest .

Comment: whats your target api. add manifest file please.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> added in Permission Section

Comment: @maheshd what about `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`

Comment: Need to add Android M runtime permission for **CALL_PHONE**. Check [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE)

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" /> my Target API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL`

And action_dial does not need permission, and it will show dialed phone number to user on dialer and then it will be users wish to place a call or not. This will be better approach to give user a control of what they wants to do.

hope that will help you

Comment: Yes Now I tried it Some thing better than previous But it Shows in 10 digit Mobile number as for Ex: (123) 456-7891

Comment: this may be default formatting by dialer, but if your security exception issues is resolved with my answer then please accept it.

Answer (score -2):

In order to use `Intent.ACTION_CALL` you have to add a permission to your manifest.

Add this permission to your manifest and it should be ok

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: I already added it But still I am Getting java.lang.SecurityException

Comment: Where you add this permission?

Comment: Added in Manifest Permission Section